# Find all non-abelian groups of order 105.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Find all non-abelian groups of order 105.

My attempt: $105=3.5.7$.

Consider the $3$-factorization, as $5, 7, 35 \not\equiv 1\mod 3$ we have that the sylow $3$-subgroup is normal.

Consider now the $7$-factorization. By this we get that there is either $15$ sylow $7$-subgroups or one normal sylow $7$-subgroup.

If there are $15$ sylow-$7$-subgroups then $[N_G(P):P]=1$ and then since $P$ is abelian we have that $N_G(P)=C_G(P)$. But this means that we have that P has a normal $p$-complement and so we have that any groups of this form can be represented as:

$<x,y |x^{15}=y^7=1, yxy^{-1}=x^\alpha >$

But what $\alpha$ are possible?

If there is one normal sylow $7$-subgroup then we have a normal subgroup of order $21$ which is abelian. Hence we have groups of this type represented by:

$<x,y |x^{21}=y^5=1, yxy^{-1}=x^\beta >$

But what $\beta$ are possible?

Comment: Hint: if $yxy^{-1} = x^{\alpha}$, then $y^2 x y^{-2} = x^{\alpha^2}$, and...

Comment: Your first error is that $7 \equiv 1$ mod 3...

Comment: [According to the small groups library](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/small/number.html), there are exactly two groups of order 105.  As $105=3\cdot5\cdot7$, there is exactly one abelian group of this order, and so there is only one non-abelian group.

Comment: @jwodder Why do you claim that there is only one non-abelian group if there is exactly one abelian group of this order?

Comment: @Bach: Because there are exactly two groups of order 105.  If only one of them is abelian, then $2-1=1$ of them must be non-abelian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\,Q_p\,$ be a Sylow p-sbgp. of $\,G\,$ . If either $\,Q_5\,,\,Q_7\,$ is normal then the product $\,P:=Q_5Q_7\,$ is a sbgp. of $\,G\,$ and thus it is normal as well, as its index is the minimal prime dividing $\,|G|\,$. In this case, and since the only existing group of order $35$ is the cyclic one, we'd get that $\,|\operatorname{Aut}(P)|=\phi (35)=24$, and thus we can define a homomorphism $\,Q_3=\langle c\rangle\to\operatorname{Aut}(P=\langle d\rangle)\,$ by $\,d^c:= c^{-1}dc\,$ . As this homom. isn't trivial (of course, we assume at least one of the Sylow sbgps. is non-normal) we get a (non-abelian, of course) semidirect product $$ P\rtimes Q_3 $$ .

If both $\,Q_5,Q_7\,$ are not normal, a simple counting argument tells us there are $\,90\,$ elements of order $7$ and $84$ elements of order 5, which is absurd as we've only $\,105\,$ elements in the group.

Thus, the above is the only way to get a non-abelian group of the wanted order.

Comment: Long time's gone, but I'd have a couple of points. 1)  "of course, we assume at least one of the Sylow sbgps. is non-abelian": but they are all three cyclic, and why would you need that, anyway? 2) Why not considering the mixed cases also, when one only between $Q_5$ and $Q_7$ is normal (to rule out, in case)?

Comment: @Devo Wow, I can hardly remember...well, in fact I can't. Anyway, the "non-abelian" thing seems to be a typo. It must be "non-normal" . The second question isn't clear to me

Comment: Ah ok, but then I wonder why you need the fixed sentence sentence in round brackets (about my second question, forget it, I had misread a previous point).

Comment: @Devo Well, that one in round brackets is easy, I believe, to explain: we're trying to find all the non-abelian groups of order $\;105=3\cdot5\cdot7\;$. The second part of my answer (the counting argument) makes clear that it must be that either $\;Q_5,\,Q_7\;$ is normal and thus automatically $\;Q_5Q_7\;$ is a subgroup of $\;G\;$. Since all the Sylow sbgps. of $\;G\;$# are normal $\;\implies\;$ G is abelian, we can assume at least one of them isn't normal, I hope this makes things clearer to you.

Comment: Perfectly, I had forgotten that implication. Thanks