# If $G$ be a group of order $105$ and if a Sylow $3$- subgroup is normal in $G$, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, sylow-theory

I am fully aware that this question has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666578/when-g-105-and-has-a-normal-sylow-3-subgroup-then-g-is-abelian), but I have thaught a completely different argument without taking any help from google and I would be glad if someone verifies my proof.

> Since $|G|=105=3\cdot 5\cdot 7$, and a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$ is
> normal in $G$, a consequence of Sylow's theorem tells us that this
> Sylow $3$-subgroups is unique, call it $P.$
>
> Therefore this subgroup $P$ is invariant under every automorphism of
> G. So $P$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G.$
>
> In particular, $P$ is invariant under action by conjugation. One other
> such subgroup of $G,$ which is invariant under action by conjugation
> is the center $Z(G)$ of $G.$
>
> But all automorphisms of $G$ can not fix $Z(G).$ For example in $D_4$
> for a fixed $g\in D_4,$ $a\mapsto ga, a\in D_4 $ is an automorphism of
> $D_4$. If we denote $r\colon=$ rotation through $90^\circ$ in the positive sense and
> $f\colon=$ flip about vertical axis, the center of $D_4$ is
> $Z(G)=\langle r^2,f \rangle.$ But $ r\cdot Z(G)=\langle r^3,rf
>  \rangle\ne Z(G)$
>
> So, $P$ is contained in $ Z(G)$ and since $P$ is a characteristic
> subgroup of $G$ we can say that $P$ is a normal subgroup of $Z(G)$.
> But the smallest normal subgroup containing $P$ is $N_{G}(P),$ the
> normaliser of $P$ in $G$. Therefore $N_{G}(P)\le Z(G).$
>
> Hence we get, $|G\colon Z(G)|\le|G\colon N_{G}(P)|$
>
> $\implies|G\colon Z(G)|\le|G\colon G|[\because \text{P is normal in G,
> }N_{G}(P)=G]$
>
> $\implies  \dfrac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}\le1$
>
> $\implies  |G|\le|Z(G)|$
>
> hence $G=Z(G)$, in other words, $G$ is abelian.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: No, your proof is not correct. The fact that $Z(G)$ is invariant under conjugation implies nothing about other subgroups that are invariant under conjugation. It in no way implies that $P\leq Z(G)$. It's like saying "My hair is black, and Paul Atreides' hair is black, therefore I am Paul Atreides."

Comment: But $P$ is invariant under all automorphisms, and $Z(G)$ is invariant under conjugation, and other automorphisms may not preserve $Z(G).$ Doesn't that imply $P$ is inside $Z(G)?$

Comment: A subgroup can be invariant under all automorphisms and not even be abelian. Invariant doesn't mean every element is fixed, it just means that the elements all stay in the subgroup.

Comment: Ohh yes, got the point. Thank you, let me think another way.

Comment: @downvoter please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote.